# editing a sqllite database from the command line within an iPad

Tags: ipad, sqlite

I'm running a technical demo - it requires altering a SQLite database on an jailbroken iPad.  At the moment I'm pulling the database off via SCP and altering it with a GUI I have lying around, (very new to SQLite).  This takes time so ideally I'd like to be able to alter the SQLite database from the command line within the iPad - any recommendations for how that might work out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, jailbreak your iPad and install sqlite and openssh in cydia.

Then connect to that iPad via ssh remotely or use some ssh app like iSSH. You can also use the Mobile Terminal app from Cydia, but I don't think it works very well.

Comment: That's great - and it's actually how I'm already doing it - but I'm interested to know how about the command syntax to edit the sqllite via ssh...

Answer (score 2):

I would like to bring up that you do not need to jailbreak your iPad in order to pull this off.  You may still want it jailbroken for other reasons, but that is up to you.

First download iSSH from the Apple store.  It is $10, but it is worth every penny.  That will allow you to securely log into the server that already stores the SQLite database.  You said that you are currently using SCP to access the database, so SSH is already set up for you on the server side.  Just log into the server with the same credentials you use to SCP to/from it.

If you are SSHing in, you aren't going to have access to a GUI program to alter the SQLite database.  You will have to do it using the SQLite command line tool "sqlite3".  This really is easier than you think it is, and I personally feel that using the command line interface for SQL databases really help you understand them much better.